# Defining a monoid instance for a record type

Tags: haskell, typeclass, monoids

Suppose I have a type like

```
data Options = Options
  { _optionOne :: Maybe Integer
  , _optionTwo :: Maybe Integer
  , _optionThree :: Maybe String
  } deriving Show
```

with many more fields.  I would like to define a `Monoid` instance for this type, for which the `mempty` value is an `Options` with all fields `Nothing`.  Is there a more concise way to write this than

```
instance Monoid Options where
  mempty = Options Nothing Nothing Nothing
  mappend = undefined
```

which would avoid the need to write a bunch of `Nothing`s when my `Options` has a ton more fields?

Comment: Do you want to have `mappend = undefined` in your real `Monoid` instance, or will it join somehow two `Options` values?

Comment: You could do this, but it makes me wonder whether we will save much effort with this. The idea of definining a `Monoid` is to define such `mempty` "for once and for all".

Comment: @0xd34df00d I left it `undefined` because it's not part of the question.  I will, of course, eventually define it.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I can write `Nothing` fifteen times, for sure.  I was just wondering if there was a slick way to populate a record type with all the same value.  Or maybe a way to use the monoid instance for `Maybe a`.

Comment: You can use `Monoid` instance for `Maybe a`, but it doesn't solve the problem you are asking about: `mempty = Options mempty mempty mempty`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend just writing the `Nothing`s, or even spelling out all the record fields explicitly, so you can be sure you don’t miss a case when adding new fields with a different `mempty` value, or reordering fields:

```
mempty = Options
  { _optionOne = Nothing
  , _optionTwo = Nothing
  , _optionThree = Nothing
  }
```

I haven’t tried it before, but it seems you can use the [generic-deriving](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/generic-deriving-1.12.1) package for this purpose, as long as all the fields of your record are `Monoid`s. You would add the following language pragma and imports:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
import GHC.Generics (Generic)
import Generics.Deriving.Monoid
```

Add `deriving (Generic)` to your data type and wrap all your non-`Monoid` fields in a type from `Data.Monoid` with the combining behaviour you want, such as `First`, `Last`, `Sum`, or `Product`:

```
data Options = Options
  { _optionOne :: Last Integer
  , _optionTwo :: Last Integer
  , _optionThree :: Maybe String
  } deriving (Generic, Show)
```

Examples:

- `Last (Just 2) <> Last (Just 3)` = `Last {getLast = Just 3}`
- `First (Just 2) <> First (Just 3)` = `First {getFirst = Just 2}`
- `Sum 2 <> Sum 3` = `Sum {getSum = 5}`
- `Product 2 <> Product 3` = `Product {getProduct = 6}`

Then use the following function(s) from `Generics.Deriving.Monoid` to make your default instance:

```
memptydefault :: (Generic a, Monoid' (Rep a)) => a
mappenddefault :: (Generic a, Monoid' (Rep a)) => a -> a -> a
```

In context:

```
instance Monoid Options where
  mempty = memptydefault
  mappend = ...
```

Comment: I think spelling the field names out directly actually makes it more likely that you’d miss a case here, since it will no longer give an error if there is a missing one.

Comment: @DavidYoung `-Wmissing-fields` is on by default.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I went with just writing out all the fields, as I agree it's the most thoughtful way to do it.  ("Explicit is better than implicit" or some such thing.)

Answer (score 3):

If the `Monoid` instance for your record type follows naturally from the `Monoid` instances of the record fields, then you could use [Generics.Deriving.Monoid](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/generic-deriving-1.12.1/docs/Generics-Deriving-Monoid.html). The code could would look like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}

import GHC.Generics
import Generics.Deriving.Monoid

data Options = { .. your options .. }
             deriving (Show, Generic)

instance Monoid Options where
  mempty = memptydefault
  mappend = mappenddefault
```

Note that the record fields have to be `Monoid` too, so you will have to wrap your `Integer`s into `Sum` or `Product` (or possibly some other `newtype`) depending on the exact behavior you want.

Then, assuming you want the resulting monoid to be synced with addition on top of `Integer` and use the `Sum` newtype, the resulting behavior would be:

```
> mempty :: Options
Options {_optionOne = Nothing, _optionTwo = Nothing, _optionThree = Nothing}
> Options (Just $ Sum 1) (Just $ Sum 2) (Just $ Sum 3) <> Options (Just $ Sum 1) (Just $ Sum 2) Nothing
Options {_optionOne = Just (Sum {getSum = 2}), _optionTwo = Just (Sum {getSum = 4}), _optionThree = Just (Sum {getSum = 3})}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [generic-monoid](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/generic-monoid) package on hackage. Specifically, the [Data.Monoid.Generic](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/generic-monoid-0.1.0.1/docs/Data-Monoid-Generic.html) module. We can automatically derive the semigroup and monoid instances with the [DerivingVia](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#extension-DerivingVia) extension. That way you can avoid having to write extensive `mappend` and `mempty` functions when your records are large and every field in the record is already a monoid. The documentation gives the following example:

```
data X = X [Int] String
  deriving (Generic, Show, Eq)
  deriving Semigroup via GenericSemigroup X
  deriving Monoid    via GenericMonoid X
```

This works because `[Int]` is a monoid and `String` is a monoid. In both fields `mappend` is concatenation and `mempty` is the empty list `[]` and empty string `""`.Therefore we can make `X` a monoid.

```
X [] "" == (mempty :: X)
True
```

Keep in mind, Haskell requires that you need a semigroup if you want to define a Monoid. We see that the [typeclass of Monoid](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Monoid) has the `Semigroup` constraint:

```
class Semigroup a => Monoid a where
 ...
```

Unfortunately not all fields are monoids in your `Option` record. Specifically, `Maybe Int` does not satisfy the `Semigroup` constraint out-of-the-box because Haskell doesn't know how you want to `mappend` two `Int`s, perhaps you would add `(+)` them or maybe you'd like to multiply `(*)` them etc. We can fix this easily by borrowing common monoids from [Data.Monoid](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html) (or writing our own) and making all the fields of `Option` monoids.

```
{-# DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# DerivingVia   #-}

import GHC.Generics
import Data.Monoid
import Data.Monoid.Generic

data Options = Options
  { _optionOne   :: First Integer
  , _optionTwo   :: Sum   Integer
  , _optionThree :: Maybe String
  } 
  deriving (Generic, Show, Eq)
  deriving Semigroup via GenericSemigroup Options
  deriving Monoid    via GenericMonoid Options
```

You left the `mappend` function undefined in the question so I just picked some monoids at random to show variety (you may find the [`Maybe` wrappers](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#g:4) interesting because their `mempty` is `Nothing`). `First`'s `mappend` always picks the first argument over the second and its `mempty` is `Nothing`. `Sum`'s `mappend` just adds `Integer`s and its `mempty` is zero `0`. `Maybe String` is already a monoid with `mappend` as `String` concatenation and `mempty` as `Nothing`. Once each field is a monoid, we can derive the semigroup and monoid via `GenericSemigroup` and `GenericMonoid`.

```
mempty :: Options
Options {
  _optionOne = First { getFirst = Nothing },
  _optionTwo = Sum { getSum = 0 },
  _optionThree = Nothing
}
```

Indeed, `mempty` matches our expectation and we didn't have to write any monoid or semigroup instances for our `Options` type. Haskell was able to derive it for us!

P.S. A quick note about using `Maybe a` as a monoid. Its `mempty` is `Nothing`, but it also requires `a` to be a semigroup. If either argument to `mappend` (or since we're talking about semigroups its `<>`) is `Nothing`, then the other argument is chosen. However, if both arguments are `Just`, we use `a`'s underlying semigroup instance's `<>`.

```
instance Semigroup a => Semigroup (Maybe a) where
    Nothing <> b       = b
    a       <> Nothing = a
    Just a  <> Just b  = Just (a <> b)

instance Semigroup a => Monoid (Maybe a) where
    mempty = Nothing
```

Comment: I wrote about changing behaviour of fields without modifying the datatype ([DerivingVia sums-of-products](https://iceland_jack.brick.do/e28e745c-40b8-4b0b-8148-1f1ae0c32d43)): deriving Monoid via `GenericallySOP (PretendingVia Options '[ '[ First Integer, Maybe (Sum Integer), Maybe String ] ])`